# DataStax: Will back up work if OpsCenter goes down

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

If I configure backups with OpsCenter will the agents continue to function, will the back up service still run, if OpsCenter goes down?

Or do I need to build redundancy/set up cron jobs to complete snap shots and  incremental backups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backups will stop if you loose opscenterd. You may want to set up HA opscenter if you need guarantees that your backups will happen on opscenter downtime:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/configFailover.html

Comment: Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 0):

Note that Opscenter only provides node level snapshots and does not give you a cluster wide, consistent snapshot. This means, you may lose data if a Cassandra node goes down during a backup window. Any change in the cluster topology during the backup window may also result in some data loss. So you should be careful to schedule them appropriately.

If you need your backups to be resilient across Cassandra node failures and topology changes, you may want to checkout “[DatosIO](http://datos.io/)”.

Comment: Thanks for the help but DatosIO doesn't look mature enough for us to look at. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of commercial and opensource solutions appearing in the market.  Check out [Priam](https://github.com/Netflix/Priam) and [Talena](http://www.talena-inc.com) if you interested in Cassandra backup.  They provide the capabilities you are referring to.